# Regular Expression for Finding N or More Continuous Zeros in the String

Tags: java, regex, string

I trying to figure out how to contruct a regex which will check whether my string matches the following pattern:

> if N or more continuous zeros are present in the string, then it
>   should say mathches, otherwise, say not mathces.

I trying to implement this in Java. I know that I need to use the mathches(regex: String) method of String class in order to check the existance of the pattern, however, I do not know how to construct the regex itself.

Comment: I'm quite sure this is more of a `google how to do regex in java` question

Comment: `0{N}` will be sufficient

Comment: `0{100}`, replace 100 with the actual N

Comment: Before posting on Stackoverflow, [search and research](/help/how-to-ask). There are tons of answers to this kind of question all over the internet already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For N zeros you can do

```
// anything with n continuous zeros in it.
boolean matches = str.matches(".*0{"+n+"}.*");
```

Or you can use

```
boolean matches = Pattern.compile("0{"+n+"}").matcher(str).find();
```

Comment: Doesn't Java have a Find function or such so that the entire string doesn't have to be matched?

Comment: The first one is simpler, I guess, thanks. @PeterLawrey